# Homotopy type of complement to $xy=1$ in $\mathbb C^2$

Tags: general-topology

Question 1: Is $\mathbb{C}^2 \backslash \{ xy=1\}$ homotopic to $\mathbb{C}^2 \backslash \{ xy=0\}$?

Question 2: If not, what is the homotopy type of $\mathbb{C}^2 \backslash \{ xy=1\}$? E.g, is it homotopic to $S^1 \vee S^2$?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are complex coordinate or real?

Comment: $x, y$ are complex variables, sorry for the confusion.